# How to create a dynamic key in my JSON object from the Angularjs received data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, amcharts

I need some data to create graphs using Amcharts.
The `chartData` is the array containing all the data to represent in a graph.

Here is my code:

```
chartData6.push({
                "Concession": $scope.concessionName,
                "Total missions": $scope.nbMission,
                $scope.brandName :$scope.nbMissionTotal
            });
```

`$scope.brandName` is a dynamic value. I am not able to push it and my code won't even compile?
What should I do?

Comment: [$scope.brandName]

Comment: `var obj = {"Concession": $scope.concessionName, "Total missions": $scope.nbMission }; obj[$scope.brandName] =$scope.nbMissionTotal; chartData6.push( obj );`

Comment: first create an object to be pushed. lets say x = {}; then add what you want to add as static properties. then use x[$scope.theName] = "something"

Comment: @alon eitan why? there are just two chars needed to make the OPs code work...

Comment: @Jonasw I swear I didn't know about it (And a bid ashamed)! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just embed within the **`[]`**

```
chartData6.push({
  "Concession": $scope.concessionName,
  "Total missions": $scope.nbMission,
  [$scope.brandName] :$scope.nbMissionTotal
});
```